# Format pages to print in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to move pages in excel to basically split a spreadsheet in half?

Example, I have 390,000 lines in a spreadsheet.
If you were to print the spreadsheet in portrait format with a 12 size font, that would come out to about 44 lines per page at close to 8800 pages.

I want to cut that in half.

I have 3 columns.  All I want to do is bring the even pages to the odd pages, where there is plenty of room.  Can anyone advise me as to what I can do?

[image]

Comment: You should load a template file or a snapshot of what you're trying to achieve. It's not very clear in your question.

Comment: Sound like you're looking to take cut the data from rows 45-88 and paste it to the right of data in rows 1-44? And then delete the empty rows?

Comment: @Tim - yep.  That is exactly what I am trying to do.  How can I do that without having to go through 390,000 lines.

Comment: [How to print long column on one page in Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1157-excel-print-long-column-one-page.html) might be what you need.

Comment: If you produce a PDF from your-favorite-tool, you can then transform it to 2-up mode on the command line at least in Linux via the `pdfjam` package's, `pdfnup` command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254308/printing-two-pages-per-sheet-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 4):

When you go to print, set your printer settings to "2 UP" or "2 Pages per sheet".  Or try double-siding printing.  Or both.  I'm kidding here, but is printing 4400 pages really more desirable than printing 8800?  Hard to imagine anyone attempting to sort through either pile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro (after saving your file preferably).

```
Sub adsagrse()
Dim lRows As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


lRows = 45

Do While Len(Cells(lRows, 1)) > 0
    Cells(lRows, 1).Resize(44, 3).Copy Cells(lRows, 1).Offset(-44, 4)
    Cells(lRows, 1).Resize(44, 3).ClearContents
    lRows = lRows + 88
llop

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, ""
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter


With application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I got a run time error, stating that there is something wrong with this line: Cells(lRows, 1).Resize(44, 3).Copy Cells(lRows, 1).Offset(-44, 4).Copy

Comment: Remove the `.Copy` from the end of that line.

Comment: The code copied everything after line 44 into the split.  How can we have it copy only the even pages or every other 44 lines.

Comment: That lRows+44 should likely be lRows+88

Answer (score 0):

Note : that depend on the printer capabilities

let say you will print on A4 size paper with potrait in this example

1. create custom paper size with half-width of A4 size (height 297mm x width 105mm) in your printer settings

2. go to excel and print as usual but select the new custome paper size that just created

while in print - page setup 

3. set your page size same as 'A4 half-width'

4. set your print to 'print 2 pages on 1 page'

5. set your print paper output as normal A4


hope it work on your printer